# How should the toString() methods in ClassA and ClassB be written to take advantage of the natural toString() method in ClassB?

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ClassA {
 ArrayList<ClassB> list = new ArrayList<ClassB>();

 public static void main(String args[]) {
     ClassA y = new ClassA();
     int[] v = { 4, 3, 7, 5, 99, 3 };
     for (int m : v)
         y.list.add(new ClassB(m));
     System.out.println(y);
 } // end main

} // end class ClassA

class ClassB {
 int x;

 ClassB(int a) {
     x = a;
 }
} // end ClassB
```

How should the methods in ClassA and ClassB be written to give the indicated output and take advantage of the natural toString method in ClassB? (Assuming this should be ClassA?)
The output should be as follows: 4 3 7 5 99 3

For class A, I made the following changes.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ClassA {
    ArrayList<ClassB> list = new ArrayList<ClassB>();
    String numberList = "";
    public String toString() {
        for (ClassB object : list)
            numberList += object + " ";
        return numberList;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ClassA y = new ClassA();
        int[] v = {4, 3, 7, 5, 99, 3 };
        for (int m : v)
            y.list.add(new ClassB(m));
        System.out.println(y);
    } // end main
} // end class ClassA
```

For class B

```
class ClassB {
    int x;
    ClassB(int a) {
       x = a;
    }
 
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(x);
    }
} // end ClassB
```

I probably did this wrong, but does anyone have better insight on this?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem actually is, since you have not implemented `toString()` for either class nor described what is "not working" (assuming you had implemented them).

Comment: @Bohemian edited what I need to output to the terminal. Sorry about that, thanks.

Comment: Please  show the `toString()` method implementations you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 2):

Once you write a `.toString()` method in H2ClassB, then the println in H2ClassA's main method would display properly.

The instruction: `System.out.println (y);` will attempt to display an ArrayList, which has its own `toString` method, and the output would look like [stuff, stuff, stuff, stuff] , but 'stuff' will be the result of a toString of your elements of your list, which are H2ClassB objects. Without a custom `toString` you are seeing binary references in its place.